# Looking for a field in the Dataset C#

Tags: c#, mysql, datatable

I am querying the mySQL database and storing the response in datatable. I need to check for the specific column to verify if its blank or null.Below is what I am doing

```
DataTable dataTab = new DataTable("ServiceOrderProtocol");

string strQuery = "select OrderID, ServiceOrder, ExternalID, Project_key, ProjectType from ServiceOrder;";

using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(strQuery, conn))
{
using (MySqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd))
 {
 sqlDa.Fill(dataTab);
 return dataTab;
 }}
```

Now I am not sure how to check for the field ExternalID returned from the query stored in dataTab is null or empty.

Comment: A table normally stores multiple rows, do you want to know if any of them has a field `ExternalID` that is null or that all are null?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to retrieve column values separately through sql data adapter class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10805578/how-to-retrieve-column-values-separately-through-sql-data-adapter-class)

Comment: @TimSchmelter yes all the rows with ExternalId is null or blank

Comment: @MarkC. it is about the Dataset is that that the same way we deal with the DatatTable as well

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know if any of the rows in the table contains a null value in the field `ExternalID`:

```
bool anyNullExternalID = dataTab.AsEnumerable().Any(r => r.IsNull("ExternalID"));
```

If you want to know if all are null:

```
bool allNullExternalID = dataTab.AsEnumerable().All(r => r.IsNull("ExternalID"));
```

If you want all rows where it's null:

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> allNullExternalIDRows = dataTab.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(r => r.IsNull("ExternalID"));
```

---

If it's not an `int`(like the name suggests) but a `string` and you want to include `null` and an empty string, append `|| string.IsNullOrEmpty(r.Field<string>("ExternalID"))`

Comment: Can I extend that to check for the Blank too

Comment: @xyz: so it's a string? Edited my answer